# tensorboard --debug shows no info

Tags: debugging, tensorboard

I have Win7 x64, TensorFlow(GPU) 1.3.0, TensorBoard 0.1.5, Python 3.6, CUDA 8.0.
Tensorboard is working well, but when I try --debug, tensorboard says no extra line/output.
Is that correct?

```
D:>tensorboard --logdir=tr:C:\Users\Martin\tmp.tf\04_hist --debug
```

Note: "`tr:`" is there as workaround for Win.

Answer (score 0):

As for me by default with `--debug` option in Windows OS I see messages only in case of Warnings

```
(3.5-n) C:\soft\Miniconda3>tensorboard --logdi=test:D:\Projects\logs\2 --debug
TensorBoard 0.1.7 at http://PDESK:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
W1013 13:42:00.471421 Reloader tf_logging.py:86] Found more than one graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
W1013 13:42:00.510424 Reloader tf_logging.py:86] Found more than one graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
```

Answer (score 0):

presumably - you want to use tf_debug with tensorflow.

so you want to pass --debug into the python command that's running the tensorflow python code. python mnist.py

https://github.com/keisuke-nakata/keras-tfdbg-tutorial

for Keras

```
from keras import backend as K


def set_debugger_session():
    sess = K.get_session()
    sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
    sess.add_tensor_filter('has_inf_or_nan', has_inf_or_nan)
    K.set_session(sess)
```

or lookup **TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession** -

```
sess = tf_debug.TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession(sess, "127.0.0.0:6006")
```

python debug_minst.py --debug triggers tfdbg interpreter.

[image]

because you mention tensorboard - you're probably interested in the tensorboard debug plugin. I'm yet to get this working - but if you can't get that working - ask another question here on SO.